# Launching a batch file on a remote server using invoke-command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-remoting

Recently I've been having a slight problem with executing batch files on a server. Whenever I try to use `Invoke-Command` to launch a bat file (which simply creates a txt file for testing purposes), it doesn't return any errors nor creates the text file. I've been googling that thing for hours but didn't manage to find any helpful information. Perhaps I don't have specific permissions?

I use CredSSP for authentication. And I need to use `Invoke-Command` with ScriptBlock.

Code that I've been using:
Batch:

```
echo 123>test.txt
```

Powershell:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock $block -Credential $cred -Authentication CredSSP -ArgumentList $test
```

Comment: For help with your code: show your code. Batch and PowerShell.

Comment: Batch: `echo 123>test.txt`

Powershell: `invoke-command -ComputerName  $s -ScriptBlock $block -Credential $cred -Authentication CredSSP -ArgumentList $test`

Comment: Please do not bury relevant information in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: Most likely your output file is created correctly, but not where you expect it. Try with an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Last question: Does PS remoting needs different permissions to launch files such as Rar to put a document into archive?

Comment: The remote command should be running with the rights of the user whose credentials you're passing to `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Strangely, when it comes to WinRar achieve function, it doesn't do anything. Doing the command that is in scriptblock trough `Enter-PSSession`, works perfectly.